# React Native Handle Headerback with Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, header, navigation, react-navigation

I have integrated Redux to my RN Project. I can navigate between screens with buttons, but when I want to go back with the HeaderBackButton it says: "undefined is not a function"

Github-Repo: https://github.com/bayraktarhasan/React-Navigation-Redux-Globalization-Example.git

My Feed Component:

```
 class Feed extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Hello Ahmet',
    headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton onPress={this.goBack()} />,
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this);
  }

  goBack = () => {
    this.props.navBack();
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{I18n.t('feedComponent')}</Text>
        <Button
          title={I18n.t('back')}
          onPress={this.goBack}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { navBack, navToProfile })(Feed);
```

Reducer:

```
import { NAVIGATE_BACK, NAVIGATE_PROFILE, NAVIGATE_FEED } from '../Actions/types';

const firstAction = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Main');
const initialNavState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
  firstAction
);


function nav(state = initialNavState, action) {
  console.log(action.type);
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case NAVIGATE_BACK:
      nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
                  NavigationActions.back(),
                  state
                );
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but goBack isn't really defined.  Maybe try:

```
const goBack = () => {
   this.props.navBack();
}
```

This is very ironic, because I was having the same problem yesterday.  Here's the post [How to properly assign a url as a prop to action creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542369/how-to-properly-assign-a-url-as-a-prop-to-action-creator)

It might not be very clear from the above link what might need to be done in your case.  But I'll try to explain what I've discovered (I'm not an expert in any way).  Your code would work on a text input or a date picker or something of that sort.  Like this:

```
<TextInput
      label="Model"
      placeholder="4020"
      value={this.props.model}
      onChangeText={value => this.props.entryUpdate({ prop: 'model', value })}
/>
```

Where the text input has a couple of props already.  Here, you assign value to

```
this.props.<whatever you want the specific object/prop to be called>
```

But with a button, you have to assign an actual prop name/variable to pass to your action creator.  Here you don't have an actual prop.  So, it comes back as undefined.  So, you have to declare a variable name for that prop and assign it to this.props just before:

```
this.props.navBack();
```

So maybe it would be:

```
const goBack = () => {
  const { back } = this.props
    this.props.navBack({ back });
}
```

And in your case, you might need to specify a specific value for the prop { back }. Otherwise, it'll tell you that your second argument is undefined as well.

Here's a cool debugger that helps you see if your props are actually being passed to the action creator:

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Hope that helps more than it confuses.  Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't work, it give's out the same problem: "undefined is not a object"

Comment: I'm going to test it out with the debugger.I hope it will fix it. But thank you for your answer :)