# How to properly assign a url as a prop to action creator

Tags: firebase, react-native, ecmascript-6, redux, firebase-storage

I'm using react-native-image-crop-picker along with react-native-fetch-blob to grab an image from the camera roll and then save it to a Firebase storage bucket.

```
class CreateForm extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
   this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  // RNFetchBlob and RNImageCropPicker working together to store an 
  // image in firebase, and then returning a url for that image.

  openImage() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
    const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
    window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest
    window.Blob = Blob
    //const uid = "12345"

    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      cropping: true,
      mediaType: 'photo',
    }).then(image => {
      const imagePath = image.path;

      let uploadBlob = null;

     const storage = firebase.storage();
     const storageRef = storage.ref();
     const imageRef = storageRef.child('dp.jpg');
     const mime = 'image/jpg';
     fs.readFile(imagePath, 'base64')
       .then((data) => {
          //console.log(data);
       return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` });
    })
       .then((blob) => {
          uploadBlob = blob;
          return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime });
       })
      .then(() => {
          uploadBlob.close();
          return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
       })
```

Everything works perfectly until this bit of code:

```
      .then((url) => {
          console.log(url);
          this.props.entryUpdate({ prop: 'image', url });
    });
   });
  }
```

It logs the url just fine.  But when I try to assign this url as a prop named 'image' to the action creator 'entryUpdate', the Firebase realtime database gets an undefined object and throws an error.

Here's the action creator 'entryUpdate':

```
 export const entryUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
   return {
    type: ENTRY_UPDATE,
    payload: { prop, value }

  };
 };
```

Without the 'image' prop, everything executes correctly. So I know that I'm not giving the action creator the right syntax somehow. The

```
this.props.entryUpdate({ prop: 'image', url });
```

line has to be just plain wrong. Any help would be so appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're destructuring the object being passed into the action creator incorrectly, `({ prop, value })` is basically grabbing the properties from the object being passed through. `prop` is correct because the object being passed as an argument has a `prop` key with 'image' as the value. `value` however is undefined because `value` is not a defined key on the object passed as an argument. Using `url` instead would be correct and should fix your issue:

```
export const entryUpdate = ({ prop, url }) => {
   return {
    type: ENTRY_UPDATE,
    payload: { prop, url } // or { prop, value: url } if you dont want to edit your dispatcher.

  };
 };
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! I really appreciate it! What if I'm passing lots of different props into entryUpdate? Some are { prop, value }.  Is there a way to either assign url to value in my component? Or give both url and value as arguments to entryUpdate. Does that make sense? Cuz   
           const value = url;
           this.props.entryUpdate({ prop: 'image', value });   doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, with your current code, `this.props.entryUpdate({ prop: 'image', value: url });` should also work if you want to keep your action creator how it is.

Comment: Also it helps to set up redux-devtools if you haven't already to be able to view your state/action calls

Comment: Yep! That works. Thanks man! And thanks for the heads up about redux-devtools.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
.then((url) => {
      const { image } = this.props;
      this.props.entryUpdate({ prop: 'image', value: url });
```

I had to declare { image } as this.props, as well as specifying

```
value: url
```